# Implicit function in Scala not working as expected

Tags: scala

If I define the following function which expects a Long, and I define the following implicit function, the implicit function is used when I pass a Date to the first function and everything works as expected:

```
def millisToDays(in: Long): Int = (in / (1000L * 3600L * 24L)).toInt
implicit def dateToLong(d: Date) = d.getTime
println(millisToDays(new Date))
```

But for the following second example, I get a compiler error on the third line: "inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method mySum's type parameter bounds [t <: java.lang.Number]"

```
def mySum[T <: Number](as: T*): Double = as.foldLeft(0d)(_ + _.doubleValue)
implicit def intToInteger(n: Int): Integer = new Integer(n.toInt)
var r = mySum(2, 3)
```

What have I done wrong?  Why isn't the intToInteger implicit function being used?

I am guessing that the problem is that the implicit function does not return a "T <: Number", but rather an Integer, so the compiler can't guess that the implicit function is actually useful.

Is there anyway which I can give the compiler a hint that it should use the implicit function?

Thanks!
Ant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[T <: Number]` type bounds means that `T` must be a *subtype* of `Number`.  The implicit conversion from `Int` to `Integer` doesn't give you this, since even though the conversion is available it still doesn't mean that `Int` is a subtype of `Number`.

Luckily, there is something similar called view bounds, written `[T <% Number]`, which specifies exactly what you want, that there is an implicit conversion available from `T` to `Number`

Comment: If you do this, then your custom implicit `intToInteger` can be deleted, because Scala does it for you.

Comment: almost, but no cigar:  I get a different error, when I use this function definition and no implicit: "def mySum[T <% Number](as: T*): Double = as.foldLeft(0d)(_ + _.doubleValue)".  The new error is: ambiguous implicit values: both method int2Integer in object Predef of type (x: Int)java.lang.Integer and method int2bigInt in object BigInt of type (i: Int)scala.math.BigInt match expected type Int => java.lang.Number

Comment: Are you importing `scala.math.BigInt._`?  I was able to reproduce your error after doing that import.  The error is occurring because BigInt contains its own implicit conversion that conforms to `Int => Number`, and the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: yes, removing the BigInt wildcard import fixes it.  I just found this link (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/136) which states <: means subtype - the book im reading says subtype OR same type...  thanks for the answer - ill accept it :-)